# "The [Name] Trust" or “[Name] Trust”?

Tags: definite-articles

I have to write a dissertation about a charity named "St Anthony's trust".

I was puzzled about the title. Do you think that I should write

1. "Community-supported agriculture. St Anthony's trust" or
2. "Community-supported agriculture. The St Anthony's Trust"?

Sorry for my bad English but I have been started to write in this language.

Comment: Closely related: [“the Red Cross” but no article in Greenpeace, UNICEF, or Amnesty International](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/439385/the-red-cross-but-no-article-in-greenpeace-unicef-or-amnesty-international)

Comment: You have "only started to write". You want the intransitive form of **start**.   To "be started" is a passive construction (based on the transitive verb) which means someone got you started.

Comment: Is it an existing organization now?   If so, what does it call itself?

Comment: @TRomano, Yes it is. This is the web site of the organization.

http://stanthonystrust.org/

thank you very much for all the corrections!

Comment: The name is *St Anthony's Trust*. You call it what it calls itself. "Community Supported Agriculture:  St Anthony's Trust".

Comment: thanks also to @Mari-LouA of course.

Comment: The definite article could be placed in the "title" e.g. *The* Community Supported Agricultural [Charity/Organisation]: St Anthony Trust

Comment: Possible duplicate:[“the Red Cross” but no article in Greenpeace, UNICEF, or Amnesty International](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/439385/the-red-cross-but-no-article-in-greenpeace-unicef-or-amnesty-international)